# Find the size of squares cut from a box.?

Tags: functions, polynomials, functional-inequalities, rectangles

This has been taking me days to do and I really want to do it for test practice. I actually have absolutely no idea how to even start this, so if I can get a hint, advice, or something to start me off, that would be great. I just hope that the start off will actually get me to the end.

The question:

A box with no top that has a volume of 1000 cm3 is to be constructed from a 22 cm by 30 cm sheet of cardboard by cutting squares of equal size from each corner, as shown in the figure, and folding up the flaps. What size square should be cut from each corner?

Thank you :)

[image: The image of the box given]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Introduce some variables so you can use algebra to your advantage. Ask yourself what do you want to find? The size of the squares? What does size mean? Area? Okay, area is length times width. But this is a square. So let $x$ be the side of one of the squares.

Given the volume of the box we form from the sheet, can we form a meaningful equation so we can solve for $x$?